# Using local buttons in other function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, button, tkinter

I have the following code, the problem is that i cannot use in `Marca3` a button is created in `Marca2`, so i can't delete it. I think that is because is not created in the same function is used.
Supose the object C1 is already created

The code:

```
#The error says 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy''

import Tkinter
den = tkinter.Tk()

def Marca2(b):
    if b == 1:
        C1.destroy()
        J1 = Button(MenuP, text = "J1",command = lambda: Definir(1,0)).place(x = 100,y = 100) #Here is created the button

def Marca3(b):
    if b == 1:
        J1.destroy() #Here is where i use that button
        C1 = Button(MenuP, text = "1",command = lambda: Definir(1,0)).place(x = 100,y = 100)

Marca2(1)
Marca3(1)


den.mainloop()
```

Comment: The code you posted never calls `Marca2` or `Marca3`. One solution depends on how you call them, so please try to incorporate that into your example.

Comment: I edited that but is called like any function

Comment: `J1` is local variable which exists only in `Marca2`, but not in `Marca3`. You may have to use `global J1` in `Marca2` and then it will be global and it will be accesible in `Marca3` too. BTW: the same problem is `C1` - it is local variable in `Marca3` which doesn't exist in `Marca2`

Comment: You assign to `J1` and `C1` value returned by `place() / pack() / grid()` which always returns `None`, not created widget. You have to do it in two lines: `J1 = tk.Button(...)` and `J1.place(...)`

Comment: you can also create global buttons (create outside functions) and in functions use `place()` to show one and `place_forget()` to hide another one.

Comment: You should rather pass widget objects as arguments to your functions, otherwise what's the point of defining them in functions?

Comment: The point is that this is for a game and that process is needed to be repeted several times